# Задача "Кривaя Дрaкона"

Tags: c#

Решаю задачу "Кривaя Дрaкона", которая находится [здесь](https://ulearn.me/Course/BasicProgramming/Praktika_Dragon_curve__f9dd2a00-cc48-42d7-914a-813e3f9847e0). Я решил её следующим образом, и проверка была пройдена:

```
using System;
namespace Fractals
{
    internal static class DragonFractalTask
    {
        public static void Calc(double x, double y, double angle, int randomise , out double c, out double d)
        {
            var dx = (x * Math.Cos(angle) - y * Math.Sin(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2) + randomise ;
            d = (x * Math.Sin(angle) + y * Math.Cos(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2);
            c = dx;
        }
        public static void DrawDragonFractal(Pixels pixels, int numOfIterations, int seed)
        {
            double c = 1, d = 0;
            var random = new Random(seed);      
            while (numOfIterations-- > 0)
            {
                var randomise = random.Next(2);
                var angle = Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI / 2 * randomise ;
                Calc(c, d, angle, randomise , out c, out d);
                pixels.SetPixel(c, d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Однако преподаватель выделил слово void в 7 строчке с замечанием "Лучше возвращать значение". Я исправил на этот вариант:

```
using System;
 
namespace Fractals
{
    internal static class DragonFractalTask
    {
        public static (double c, double d) Calc(double x, double y, double angle, int randomise)
        {
            var dx = (x * Math.Cos(angle) - y * Math.Sin(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2) + randomise ;
            var d = (x * Math.Sin(angle) + y * Math.Cos(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2);
            var c = dx;
        }
        
        public static void DrawDragonFractal(Pixels pixels, int numOfIterations, int seed)
        {
            double c = 1, d = 0;
            var random = new Random(seed);      
            while (numOfIterations-- > 0)
            {
                var randomise = random.Next(2);
                var angle = Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI / 2 * randomise ;
                Calc(c, d, angle, randomise);
                pixels.SetPixel(c, d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь задание не проходит на проверку, видимо из-за того, что необходимо использовать возвращаемое значение, как это написать? Спасибо

Comment: "Не проходит проверку" - это вы про компиляцию? Какую именно ошибку оно показывает?

Comment: Вам нужно открыть учебник и прочитать главу про функции. Вы спрашиваете самые азы программирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По моему, Ваш преподаватель имел в виду следующее: вместо `out double c, out double d` он хочет, чтобы функция возвращала значение.
Но есть трудность. Вам нужно вернуть 2 числа, а функция возвращает одно значение.
Эту проблему можно решить созданием класса или структуры, который состоит из двух double чисел. Тогда решение будет таким:

```cs
internal static class DragonFractalTask
{
    public class TmpPair
    {
        public double c;
        public double d;
    }

    public static TmpPair Calc(double x, double y, double angle, int randomise)
    {
        var dx = (x * Math.Cos(angle) - y * Math.Sin(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2) + randomise;
        var d = (x * Math.Sin(angle) + y * Math.Cos(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2);
        var c = dx;
        TmpPair return_val = new TmpPair();
        return_val.c = c;
        return_val.d = d;
        return return_val;
    }

    public static void DrawDragonFractal(Pixels pixels, int numOfIterations, int seed)
    {
        double c = 1, d = 0;
        var random = new Random(seed);
        while (numOfIterations-- > 0)
        {
            var randomise = random.Next(2);
            var angle = Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI / 2 * randomise;
            TmpPair pair = Calc(c, d, angle, randomise);
            pixels.SetPixel(pair.c, pair.d);
        }
    }
}
```

Небольшое дополнение.

Вообще то, в C# уже существует тип, очень подходящий для возврата нескольких значений из функции. Этот тип называется Tuple<>, и с ним решение становится короче:

```cs
internal static class DragonFractalTask
{
    public static Tuple<double, double> Calc(double x, double y, double angle, int randomise)
    {
        var dx = (x * Math.Cos(angle) - y * Math.Sin(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2) + randomise;
        var d = (x * Math.Sin(angle) + y * Math.Cos(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2);
        var c = dx;
        Tuple<double, double> ret_val = new Tuple<double, double>(c, d);
        return ret_val;
    }

    public static void DrawDragonFractal(Pixels pixels, int numOfIterations, int seed)
    {
        double c = 1, d = 0;
        var random = new Random(seed);
        while (numOfIterations-- > 0)
        {
            var randomise = random.Next(2);
            var angle = Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI / 2 * randomise;
            Tuple<double, double> pair = Calc(c, d, angle, randomise);
            pixels.SetPixel(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

И наконец, есть прекрасный еще более короткий вариант, который мне в комментариях подсказал EvgeniyZ: (а также, он предлагает понятный [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7O5dt) про использование кортежей)

```cs
internal static class DragonFractalTask
{
    public static (double, double) Calc(double x, double y, double angle, int randomise)
    {

        var dx = (x * Math.Cos(angle) - y * Math.Sin(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2) + randomise;
        var d = (x * Math.Sin(angle) + y * Math.Cos(angle)) / Math.Sqrt(2);
        var c = dx;
        return (c, d);
    }

    public static void DrawDragonFractal(Pixels pixels, int numOfIterations, int seed)
    {
        double c = 1, d = 0;
        var random = new Random(seed);
        while (numOfIterations-- > 0)
        {
            var randomise = random.Next(2);
            var angle = Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI / 2 * randomise;
            (double r_c, double r_d) = Calc(c, d, angle, randomise);
            pixels.SetPixel(r_c, r_d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем такие трудности? Почему бы не просто `public static (double, double) Calc (...) { return (c, d); } `

Comment: Та же ошибка, что у автора в вопросе: не используется возвращаемое из Calc значение.

Comment: `потом мы бращаемся к результату через .Item1 и .Item2` - чтоб это предотвратить, надо его "развернуть" в понятное и читаемое, например `(double c, double d) = Calc(...);` и далее использовать уже просто `pixels.SetPixel(c, d);`. Либо можно задать названия этим `Item1` и `Item2` в самом методе (`public static (double c, double d) Calc(...)`) или при получение результата (`(double c, double d) = Calc(...)`). В общем вот, набросал [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7O5dt) про кортежи.

Comment: @S.H. спасибо, но выходит ошибка: "The type or namespace name 'Pixels' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Nik проверьте название [неймспейса](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) `Fractals`. В ответе почему-то оно с маленькой буквы.

Comment: @aepot Теперь ошибка "Wrong transformation on iteration #1
Error on test: IterationsCount = 20, Seed = 123"

Comment: @Nik это уже не ко мне, я не знаю, что это значит.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что надо сравнить первый вариант - на котором проверяющая система не ругалась - и тот, на котором она выдаёт ошибку, которую Вы написали в комментарии. Возможно, после этого сравнения всё станет ясно